# QGIS - Why calculations in the attribute table are not adapting to filter?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, filter

I want to add columns in a shapefile to make calculations on it, those calculations are supposed to measure the size per land cover type and therefore I need that my calculation adapts to my filters.

I do my filters in the query builder because it does not work from the attribute table.

When I filter my layers the results of my calculation don't change. I don't understand why and I don't know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 5):

Using a regular field calculation, the result is static and would need to be re-calculated each time a change is made. To make the output dynamic, you can create a `virtual field` that will adapt to a filter.

Here I make a field called `adaptive` that is the sum of another field `length`

[image]

With no filter applied on the layer:

[image]

With the filter `fid > 1`:

[image]

The `virtual field` persists when you save, close, and re-open your project. However, it does not exist in the actual shapefile, so you would need to export the layer as a new shapefile if you want to keep a *static* version of your result (to hand to someone else, for example).

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about these, or that there was a Field Calculator button in the Attribute Table that works slightly differently from the one in the Toolbox, like offering the Create Virtual Field option. This shouldn't have surprised me, since I came to QGIS from ArcMap, which does the same thing.